Xubuntu 22.04 and Netgear wireless
I've been scratching my head trying to figure this one out for a good minute. I'm currently using xubuntu 22.04 and my Netgear A6210 is just. Not very stable.
iwconfig: wlx3498b5a36d29  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Action Bastard"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.765 GHz  Access Point: 6C:CD:D6:0C:30:59   
          Bit Rate=702 Mb/s   Tx-Power=18 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:14   Missed beacon:0

It DOES connect, but it is VERY unstable. It disconnects a lot, speeds drop from 30mbps to 0 and it disconnects. Things lag/load VERY slow.
chris@desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c335 Logitech, Inc. G910 Orion Spectrum Mechanical Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c081 Logitech, Inc. Gaming Mouse G900
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9053 NetGear, Inc. A6210
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1462:7d14 Micro Star International MYSTIC LIGHT 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:1392 Apple, Inc. Apple Watch charger
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

So I have the A6210, and I am not sure what to do at this point.
uname -r: `chris@desktop:~$ uname -r
6.8.0-40-generic

I am not sure what else to provide, so whatever other information you need from me, let me know and I will gladly edit this post.
Editing to add: Everything is fully updated. Have run the commands to update/upgrade everything. Did it yesterday, and today when I got home from work as well since there were new packages.
chris@desktop:~$ sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
[sudo] password for chris: 
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759985.9120] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (for the first time)
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759985.9163] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf)
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759985.9759] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759985.9889] manager[0x5dc107c7e000]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Aug 15 18:13:05 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759985.9889] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0556] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0556] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "desktop"
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0577] dns-mgr[0x5dc107c5c2a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0588] manager[0x5dc107c7e000]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0588] manager[0x5dc107c7e000]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0633] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0666] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0696] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0704] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0736] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0738] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0739] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0739] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0762] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0763] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0763] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0769] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0833] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0833] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0835] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0842] manager: (enp34s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0849] settings: (enp34s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.0849] device (enp34s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.3272] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
Aug 15 18:13:06 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759986.3291] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Aug 15 18:13:07 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759987.5095] device (wlan0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Aug 15 18:13:07 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759987.5099] manager: (wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Aug 15 18:13:07 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759987.5132] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:16:00.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver mt76x2u)
Aug 15 18:13:07 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759987.5345] device (wlan0): interface index 3 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx3498b5a36d29'
Aug 15 18:13:07 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759987.5381] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8775] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8776] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlx3498b5a36d29 created
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8777] manager: (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8778] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8779] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:08 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759988.8782] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:09 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723759989.7265] agent-manager: agent[d3824d71f4ec4781,:1.48/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5466] policy: auto-activating connection 'Action Bastard' (6a172e3a-a765-4933-98b2-8fe07bdf002d)
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5469] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): Activation: starting connection 'Action Bastard' (6a172e3a-a765-4933-98b2-8fe07bdf002d)
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5469] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5470] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5472] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5473] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): Activation: (wifi) access point 'Action Bastard' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5473] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5474] sup-iface[17f5604094a385b5,0,wlx3498b5a36d29]: wps: type pbc start...
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5479] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5481] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5482] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): Activation: (wifi) connection 'Action Bastard' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5532] Config: added 'ssid' value 'Action Bastard'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5532] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5532] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5532] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5532] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5533] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5564] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 15 18:13:20 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760000.5564] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 15 18:13:23 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760003.5310] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 15 18:13:23 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760003.5310] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating


Network manager status
chris@desktop:~$ service NetworkManager status
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-08-15 18:13:05 EDT; 7min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 667 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 33448)
     Memory: 9.3M
        CPU: 119ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─667 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.0253] dhcp4 (wlx3498b5a36d29): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.0253] dhcp4 (wlx3498b5a36d29): state changed no lease
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.0254] dhcp4 (wlx3498b5a36d29): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.0256] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.0256] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.4447] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 15 18:20:40 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760440.4448] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
Aug 15 18:20:41 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760441.2072] device (wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant interface state: associated -> completed
Aug 15 18:20:41 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760441.2074] device (p2p-dev-wlx3498b5a36d29): supplicant management interface state: associated -> completed
Aug 15 18:20:42 desktop NetworkManager[667]: <info>  [1723760442.1199] dhcp4 (wlx3498b5a36d29): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.5


output of service --status-all
chris@desktop:~$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ - ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lightdm
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  pulseaudio-enable-autospawn
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common

Updated with more information
